# Tensorflow error on Python chatbot project

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on chatbot project and I got errors in python. but I do not how to fix it. can anyone help me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:/Hoc PYTHON/Chatbot/json file/versions.py", line 2, in <module>
        import tensorflow
      File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
        from tensorflow._api.v2 import audio
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow._api'
```

Comment: You should read about how python uses packages and modules. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#managing-packages-with-pip

Comment: For what I can see Jack, it seems that your tensorflow installation doesn't contain the package __api__, probably you could find something here: [Installing Tensorflow API](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html), let me jnow5 if that helped